# GAE: cookies vs datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session-cookies, app-engine-ndb

While looking for a good and efficient way to have a session in my app, I found [GAE Boilerplate](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/README.md) and [GAE Sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions).

GAEB is amazing but very vast for my needs: I don't need Federate Login nor a default User structure, but I like the design structure and the way they solved some issues (routes, forms,...).

GAES is quite simple but powerfull to treat sessions. The most I like is the way it stores everything in a cookie, in this case, it stores the full user entity in a cookie so in the next page calls, no other datastore hits are done: the user data is always read from the cookie (this need, obviusly to update the data if the user updates something, which is not usual).

In the other hand, GAEB stores only the user ID and then retrieves, on each page call, the username and the user email. This is part of the code for the BaseHandler it uses (GAEB uses NDB model):

```
@webapp2.cached_property
def username(self):
    if self.user:
        try:
            user_info = models.User.get_by_id(long(self.user_id))
            if not user_info.activated:
                self.auth.unset_session()
                self.redirect_to('home')
            else:
                return str(user_info.username)
        except AttributeError, e:
            # avoid AttributeError when the session was delete from the server
            logging.error(e)
            self.auth.unset_session()
            self.redirect_to('home')
    return None
```

Same for email, and in the render_template function it does this:

```
def render_template(self, filename, **kwargs):
    .... some code.....

    # set or overwrite special vars for jinja templates
    kwargs.update({
        'app_name': self.app.config.get('app_name'),
        'user_id': self.user_id,
        'username': self.username,
        'email': self.email,
        ... more vars ...
    })
    kwargs.update(self.auth_config)
```

It seems that reads 2 times (one for username and one for email) from the datastore, because this funcs makes `models.User.get_by_**field**(long(self.user_id))`

The only thing I don't know exactly what means is the @webapp2.cached_property, that maybe means that all this datastore reads are done from a cache and really don't hit the datastore.

Can someone tell me what is the better solution to save hits to the database? It seems that it is better to have all the user data in a cookie (obviously, secured) and don't hit the datastore on every page call, but maybe I'm mistaken (I'm relatively noob with GAE) and all this reads to datastore are cached and, then, for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving session data in the cookie is highly discouraged:

- It has to be transfered with each request (slow on mobile connections)
- The HTTP Header size you can transfer to the GAE is limited (64Kb if i remember correctly) - thats the upper bound of data you could store
- Even if you encrypt and sign your session, you would still be vulnerable to reply attacks (you cannot perform a logout safely)

I don't know the implementations you mentioned, but we have an session implementation in our CMS, see https://bitbucket.org/viur/server/src/b2e9e3dca3adabee97e1761d630600a387a02c44/session.py?at=master .
The general idea is to generate a random string (used as a session identifier).
On session load a datastore "get by key" is performed (which is cached, so if that object is still in memcache, it wont hit the datastore at all).

And saving is only performed if the data stored inside the session changed or the session has not been
updated for the last 5 minutes.
Then you can copy the values of your user object into the session and wont have an additional datastore request.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will analyze your code. Only one fast thing I saw: why you don't use NDB instead of DB. It's better, it caches automaticly the entities (or supposed to do that), so less hits to database. By the way, I refused to store the full entity in the cookie, I found more complications, like two sessions from same user in different devices...

Comment: Your code seems to be good, but I think now that I will not use sessions at all, because I only need to know the userId and the language he wants to use, so storing it on secured cookie can resolve my needs (I just retrieve it on each call, that will be really little data to retrieve, about 20 bytes).

Comment: We dont use ndb simply to be able to specify the lifetime of the memcache-entry independent of the overall cache-time of datastore entries. 

Hint for language in cookies: Searchengine spiders (like the google one) dont accept cookies. If you want them to index your site in different languages, you need a different approach :)

Comment: Umm, very good cookies hint, that I didn't know. Spiders accept sessions then?. Ok for the NDB explain, seems that you think about this a lot. I will re-think again my strategy. The only problem with your code (to me, for use in my project) is that to kill older sessions you use a Task, that needs the taks.py file, which uses more imports... and again more files with a lot of code. I must look for another way to execute the periodic taks. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it might work if you inject the session id inside all urls on your site (not storing it in an cookie), but theres no guarantee that spiders will follow that links timely. They might index your startpage now, and check these links at any later time (and that session might expired meanwhile).
Our solution is to handle the language outside the session and inject the 2 letter language code in every url ( "/" becomes "/de/" for German, "/en/" for English etc).
That works fine for spiders.
The Appengine provides a cron-api. You can just use that to kill expired sessions from the datastore.

Comment: What a pity. I liked the idea of showing all my pages with the same url, independently of the language chosen by the user. Great explanation, I will explore the cron-api. Thank you again.